# How to add font color in vue-chartjs

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js

I have the following code in a js,

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'


export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted () {
    // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'GitHub Commits',
          backgroundColor: '#ffff',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ],
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
}
```

And i want to change the color of font, because the default color is grey.

Comment: Use the web inspector to find classes/selectors/xpath to the text events you want to set the css on.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this in options... Second argument of this.renderChart.

just put the fontColor option:

```
...
mounted () {
   // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
   this.renderChart({
      labels: [...],
      datasets: [
          ...
      ],
   }, 
   {
       responsive: true, 
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       legend: {
          ...,
          fontColor: 'white'
       },
       ...
       scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                ...
                fontColor: 'white'
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                ...
                fontColor: 'white',
            }
          }]
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: ps: ...  = that means there may be more options

Comment: For RadarCharts with a single axis, add the following within the "scale" attribute:
`pointLabels: { fontColor: 'red'}`